# MSSQL character coding

Tags: php, sql-server, json, zend-framework

I'm using ZF1 and MSSQL, using freeTDS.

Today I made a backup (using "Generate script" in Studio Management) for testing purposes, and I encountered a strange problem. In DB I see that every characters like ś,ć,ż etc are saved properly, but when in ZF I run select query, I get some strange characters instead of what I see in DB.
 This is a really annoying problem, and I tried to fix it past 4-5 hours and still nothing.

What I tried:

- ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8'); in index.php
- Set column to nvarchar, nchar
- mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8')

That method at least let my see decoded JSON, but still characters are wrong decoded. (Without this method I get only error "Invalid UTF-8...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find the freetds configuration file where is located in my server

```
(/usr/local/freetds/etc/freetds.config)
```

edit the file and setting the client charset to utf8

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but still nothing. I noticed that i can add new data to DB using ć,ź etc and when i run query, i get properly decoded string without any strange characters. The problem appears only when i received data from backup. The problem appears also on sqlsrv+wamp configuration.

Comment: Well, it so happens that you were right. I put this 'client charset' in wrong place...Thank you !